# Javascript memory representation

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, spidermonkey, jxcore

Is there any way to dump the environment records at some point during the execution of a Javascript program ?

I want to detect if two variables, or object properties are pointing to the same address, thus potentially producing "side-effects".
I think one way to do it, is to get the bindings allocation address from an environment record.

Any tools are welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: If those are objects, just `a == b`, if those are of value type - then one cannot affect the other.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

Comment: [node-debug](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector), the [native debugger](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html) or any other debugger should get you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox/Spidermonkey the thing you're looking for is called [GC/CC logs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Performance/GC_and_CC_logs). You can dump it from the browser (e.g. via [about:memory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Performance/about:memory)) or from the command-line JS shell.

When you do, you'll find that a typical JS program has a rather large and complex graph of objects and properties, so finding the aliasing cases that you're interested in will be hard.

If, on the other hand, you have the list of *object* references you're interested in, checking with `===` is enough. (See also [*Equality comparisons and sameness* on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness).